# Angular5 routing issue

Tags: angular, angularfire2, auth-guard

Working on an angular5 facing router issues while navigating from one component to another 
The error says: Cannot activate an already activated outlet
Please find the screenshot for code, header nav and error.
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQcg8.png),

[image]
[routing module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSdLy.png)[image]
 [auth guard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbWka.png)[image]

> ```
> auth guard.ts
> ```

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
        return Observable.from(this.auth.authState)
            .take(1)
            .map(state => !!state) 
            .do(authenticated => {
                if(!authenticated) 
                   this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            })
    }
}
```

> theme-routing.module.ts

```
    const routes: Routes = [
    {
        'path': '',
        'component': ThemeComponent,
        'canActivate': [AuthGuard],
        'children': [
            {
                'path': 'index',
                'loadChildren': '.\/pages\/default\/blank\/blank.module#BlankModule',
            },
            {
                'path': 'profile',
                'loadChildren': '.\/pages\/default\/profile\/profile.module#ProfileModule',
            },
            {  
                'path': 'stylists',
                'loadChildren': '.\/pages\/default\/stylists\/stylists.module#StylistsModule',
            },
            {
                'path': 'customers',
                'loadChildren': '.\/pages\/default\/customers\/customers.module#CustomersModule',
            },
            {
                'path': 'services',
                'loadChildren': '.\/pages\/default\/services\/services.module#ServicesModule',
            },
            {
                'path': '',
                'redirectTo': '/index',
                'pathMatch': 'full',
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        'path': '**',
        'redirectTo': 'index',
        'pathMatch': 'full',
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class ThemeRoutingModule {
 }
```

[screenshot of the file structure of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GiQw.png)

Comment: Provide Code instead of images.

Comment: Can you add some code in here. Without uploading images

Comment: @Vikas added the code, please check, thanks

Comment: @AnuradhaGunasekara added the code, please check, thanks